# Handling focus loss of application

Tags: events, windows-phone-7, background

I am attempting to handle the loss of focus of my application, either by a phone call or other event, and also by the pressing of the home key.

I have tried setting a flag in the OnNavigatingFrom/OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo event handlers but each time the app starts (either after pressing home, or something else) it always seems to be resetting the flag.

Which are the correct events I should be using in order to correctly "pause" and subsequently "resume" my application if it loses focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation about application lifecycle.
When you press the Home button, or when you receive a phone call, the application is paused.
If you pressed Home, you can then restore the application by pressing the back button.

to handle these events, in App.xaml.cs by default the methods are: Application_Activated and Application_Deactivated

Of course you can manage to store data before the pause, and restore it when application is restored.

This is called tombstoning.

What you need is described in the following links:

http://windowsphone7.vectorform.com/2010/11/16/wp7-application-lifecycle/

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Application-Lifecycle-and-Tombstoning

Comment: Thanks, I did some reading on this, I'm not entirely sure I understand how it works. When "tombstoned" is all the applications data unloaded and I need to start again or save it in a state? If so, It's easier for me to just store an integer value of the current "position" in my application and restart from that point on resume.

Comment: When your application is paused, the system will not save your data. It's your job. You can save in a state or in the istolatedstorage anything you want to be restored. When the application is re-activated, you will end up on the same page as when it was paused. So you need to restore anything that was displayed before the desactivation.

Comment: I see, so we're not really "backgrounding" the application. It's terminating it... I have just tried implementing this and for some reason when I press home then press back to resume it gets stuck on "Resuming..." and goes nowhere.

Comment: One caveat: Application_Deactivated/Activated will always be called when the application loses/regains focus - however, the application will not always be terminated!   For instance, using a PhoneChooserTask does not terminate the application.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967547%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). This is a microsoft tutorial on how to save state.

It'll give you how to save your ApplicationData when it is tombstoned.

Basically edit the `Application_Closing` and `Application_Activated` methods in the App.xaml to save the data to the system using isolated storage.